# Assembly language loop only goes through one iteration?

Tags: loops, gcc, assembly, gnu

Been working on this assignment all day and cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. My code is supposed to use a nested loop to print something like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxx
xxxxxxx
xxxxxx
xxxxx
xxxx
xxx
xx
x
```

The code I've written for this is:

```
# printStars2.s

# Useful constants
    .equ STDOUT,1
# Stack frame
    .equ theChar,-1
    .equ counter,-8
    .equ lineCounter, -16
    .equ localSize,-32
newline:
    .string "\n"
    .equ newlineSz,.-newline-1          # equate msgSz to # of chars

# Code
    .text
    .globl main
    .type main, @function
main:
    pushq %rbp # save base pointer
    movq %rsp, %rbp # set new base pointer
    addq $localSize, %rsp # for local var.

    movb $'*', theChar(%rbp) # character to print
    movl $10, counter(%rbp) # innerLoop control variable
    movl $10, lineCounter(%rbp) #outerLoop control variable

outerLoop:
    jmp innerLoop          # jumps to innerLoop
    decl lineCounter(%rbp) # lineCounter--
    movl lineCounter(%rbp), %ebx #copies lineCounter value to intermediate register
    movl %ebx, counter(%rbp) # copies lineCounter value from register to innerLoop counter
    cmpl $0, lineCounter(%rbp) #checks if outerLoop has gone through 10 iterations
    jne outerLoop #repeat if not
    jmp exitLoop #exitLoop when complete

innerLoop:
    leaq theChar(%rbp), %rsi # address of char
    movl $1, %edx # one character
    movl $STDOUT, %edi # standard out
    call write # invoke write function
    decl counter(%rbp) # counter--;
    jg innerLoop # repeat if > 0
    #newLine
    movl    $newlineSz, %edx        # message size
    movl    $newline, %esi          # address of message text string
    movl    $STDOUT, %edi       # standard out
    call    write               # invoke write function

exitLoop:
    movl $0, %eax # return 0;
    movq %rbp, %rsp # restore stack pointer
    popq %rbp # restore base pointer
    ret
```

When I run it it only goes through the loop one time it seems like, it only prints one row of 10 stars. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After entering `outerLoop`, you jump to `innerLoop`.

There you print stars and loop around, until the counter hits 0 (lines 37–42).

Then you print a newline (lines 44–47).

Then you return, and the program ends.

At no point do you jump back to `outerLoop`, so there is no looping!

One solution: Replace the `jmp innerLoop` instruction with the contents of the inner loop. Then, when the inner loop is done, it will continue on to the logic you wrote for the outer loop and everything will work. Since your labels `outerLoop:` and `innerLoop:` will then be right next to eachother, you can combine them and just have `Loop:`.

This [organization](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc032c87cc14f22d) also obviates the need to jump to exitLoop.